# Pass a table array as a parameter to an upsert function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, functions, array, upsert

i have an UPSERT function which works well but i update and insert records in batches, can this function be modified so that i just pass all the records to this function as an array then it will insert/update ALL the records at once as ONE TRANSACTION? if record number x fails,it should roll back undo any records that had been inserted/updated before x?
here is my upsert function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_weights(rec tbl_weightment)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
myoutput text :='Nothing has occured';
BEGIN

    update tbl_weightment set 
    vname=rec.vname,
    iquality=rec.iquality,
    vhooks=rec.vhooks,
    tstamp=rec.tstamp
    vtare=rec.vtare,
    vgross=rec.vgross     
    WHERE id=rec.id;

    IF FOUND THEN
        myoutput:= 'Record successfully updated';
        RETURN myoutput;
    END IF;

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_weightment SELECT(rec).*;
        myoutput:= 'Record successfully added';           
    END;
 RETURN myoutput;

    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

can this function be modified to be like `save_weights(rec tbl_weightment[])` ??
any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I think yes.  Haven't tried with actual INSERTs or UPDATEs yet, but this function works:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraytest2(rec a[]) RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$body$
SELECT b.*
FROM unnest($1) b;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

This way you can write your INSERT statement as

```
INSERT INTO tbl_weightment 
SELECT (r).*
FROM unnest(rec) r;
```

And UPDATE as

```
UPDATE tbl_weightment 
SET 
    vname = r.vname,
    iquality = r.iquality,
    vhooks = r.vhooks,
    tstamp = r.tstamp
    vtare = r.vtare,
    vgross = r.vgross 
FROM unnest(rec) r
WHERE id=rec.id;
```

Comment: this answer works but how about if one record in the array is faulty? how do we rollback everything and return "record no 79 missing something "??

Comment: @indago actually what you'd like to know is how to add exception handling to the function?